# How can I use the SelectedRow object of a MVC WebGrid from within the same view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a MVC WebGrid on a page and I have a selection link on my grid for each row.  From within the same view I'd like to get the model object associated with the `WebGrid.SelectedRow` object and use it within the view.

Every example I've found that accesses the `SelectedRow` object provides instructions on how to use the object for passing the object into another view/partial view.  In my case I'd like to access this object from within the same view as the WebGrid.

Here is some generalized sample code, with error-related comments.

```
@{

    var grid = new WebGrid(dataCollection)
    @grid.GetHTML(columns: "ID", "User ID"), 
        grid.Column("UserName","Name"),
        grid.Column("", format: @<text>@item.GetSelectLink("Edit")</text>)
}

<!-- FURTHER DOWN IN MY MARKUP //-->

<div class="widget">
@if(grid.HasSelection)
{
    var obj = @grid.SelectedRow;

    //The example below reports the following error when 
    //navigating to this page:
    //
    //CS0039: Cannot convert type 
    //  'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' to 
    //  'Models.User' via a reference 
    //  conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, 
    //  wrapping conversion, or null type conversion
    usr = obj as User;
    if (usr != null) <text>usr.ID</text>;
         <!-- FIND A WAY TO PRINT SELECTED CONTENT -->
}
</div>
```

I've also tried casting statements such as `((User)@grid.SelectedRow)`.  In such a case, the page will load, but as soon as I attempt to select a record and the above line is hit, the browser gives me different but similar error.

How can I access and use the `WebGrid.SelectedRow` model object from within the same view as my WebGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following answer will help you. It will display the selected row content

```
@{
    List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1001", PersonName = "Satya Nadella" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1002", PersonName = "Lisa Su" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1003", PersonName = "Jeff Clarke" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1004", PersonName = "Mark Fields" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1005", PersonName = "Phebe Novakovic" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1006", PersonName = "Mary T. Barra" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1007", PersonName = "Rajeev Suri" });
    person.Add(new Person { PersonCode = "1008", PersonName = "Michel Combes" });
}

@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(person, rowsPerPage: 10);

    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("PersonCode", "Code"), grid.Column("PersonName", "Name"), grid.Column("", format: @<text>@item.GetSelectLink("Edit")</text>)))
}

<div>
    @if (grid.HasSelection)
    {
        if (grid.SelectedRow != null)
        {
            <div>
                Code: @grid.SelectedRow.Value.PersonCode
            </div> 
            <div>
                Name: @grid.SelectedRow.Value.PersonName
            </div> 
        }        
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This works.  I was unaware of the `Value` property.  Putting breakpoints in the code, and inspecting the values in memory alluded to something different.  Specifically that the `SelectedRow` object should have been my model object.  Thank you.